# Xamarin Forms Initialize plugin in Application Class

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm using Cross Geeks Push Notification plugin. Working well while the app is in the foreground or background but it does not receive notifications in the killed state. I have compiled in Release mode and removed debug logging to no avail.

I think the issue is when\where I'm initializing the plugin. According to the FAQ's

"Android initialization should be done on and **Android Application class** to be able to handle received notifications when application is closed. Since no activity exist when application is closed."

My question is in Xamarin Forms, the "Application Class" is the app.cs which does not have a context. I'm currently initializing the plugin in the MainActivity in the OnCreate() method which Obviously isn't correct.

```
#if DEBUG
        AzurePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,Global.PushNotificationsHubEndpoint,Global.PushNotificationsHubName,true);
```

## else

```
        AzurePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, Global.PushNotificationsHubEndpoint, Global.PushNotificationsHubName, true);
```

## endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this demo of [this link](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/AzurePushNotificationPlugin/tree/master/samples/AzurePushNotificationSample), these code should be added to here like this:

> AzurePushNotificationPlugin/samples/AzurePushNotificationSample/AzurePushNotificationSample.Android/MainApplication.cs

```
namespace AzurePushNotificationSample.Droid
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : Application
    {
        protected MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                //Change for your default notification channel id here
                AzurePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "DefaultChannel";

                //Change for your default notification channel name here
                AzurePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
            }

            #if DEBUG
                 AzurePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, AzureConstants.ListenConnectionString, AzureConstants.NotificationHubName, true);
            #else
                 AzurePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, AzureConstants.ListenConnectionString, AzureConstants.NotificationHubName, false);
            #endif


            //Handle notification when app is closed here
            CrossAzurePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {


            };            
        }


    }
}
```